# Eliminate lambda in Scheme?

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, scheme, lambda-calculus

I need to eliminate this Scheme lambda construction for my school assignment.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

```
(define (foo x)
(letrec
  ((h 
    (lambda (y z)
      (cond
        ((null? y) 'undefined)
        ((null? (cdr y)) (car z))
        (else (h (cddr y) (cdr z)))
        ))))
  (h x x))
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could replace the `lambda` expression in the `letrec` with an internal definition:

```
(define (foo x)
  (define (h y z)
    (cond
      ((null? y) 'undefined)
      ((null? (cdr y)) (car z))
      (else (h (cddr y) (cdr z)))))
  (h x x))
```

... Or you could extract the `h` procedure outside of `foo`, as a helper procedure. Either way the result would be the same.

Comment: I don't really understand why they would ask them to do that in an assignment. It seems that the other way (seeing that an internal definition is a `letrec`) is more instructive